# Take the position of the texts from a psd file

Tags: photoshop, psd

I would like to create a software/script that is able to extract from a psd file all fonts (type, size and position). I opened the psd file with a text editor and I found where they are positioned on the type and size of the font, but I can not find where it marked the position of the font (pixel position from the margins of the sheet) Can you help me? Or do you know any software that does this work?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be looking for the bounds of the artLayer object.  You may need to rasterize your text and then look at the bounds of the rasterized layer if you want the position of the actual letters, as opposed to the text frame.

Comment: ideal for me would be to do everything without opening photoshop.
There is no way to rasterize without using photoshop?
and another thing, how are encoded the psd file? I read things like this: .........4e4ž4Ø55M5‡5Â5ý676r6®6é7$7`7œ7×88P8Œ8È99B99¼9ù:6:t:²:ï;-;k;ª;è...........

Comment: Ah, sorry didn't realize you were actually looking for the info from the psd itself.  In that case I don't have an answer for you - other than to say that it is likely the artLayer bounds that are recorded, which may not match exactly the bounds of the letters.  I think you'd need to open the document to rasterize the layer.